# Axis2's wsdl2java fails on RPC/Encoded style web services

Tags: java, apache-axis, axis, wsdl2java, jax-rpc

Is there any alternative to Axis2? Or the way to make it work (different data binding, for example)?

```
Retrieving document at '...'.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:271)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(SimpleDBExtension.java:53)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:224)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(SimpleDBExtension.java:50)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompilationException: can not find type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}Array from the parent schema ...        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.copyMetaInfoHierarchy(SchemaCompiler.java:1296)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexContent(SchemaCompiler.java:1258)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processContentModel(SchemaCompiler.java:1153)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1097)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1017)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:931)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:766)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:552)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.process(SchemaCompiler.java:1991)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processParticle(SchemaCompiler.java:1874)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1081)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1017)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:931)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:766)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:552)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.process(SchemaCompiler.java:1991)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processParticle(SchemaCompiler.java:1874)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1081)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processAnonymousComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:980)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:934)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:592)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:563)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:280)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.ExtensionUtility.invoke(ExtensionUtility.java:103)
        ... 8 more
```

NOTE: Apache CXF fails as well :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are only 3 options that I have found that can be used in Java for old-style rpc/encoded web services:

1) SUN's reference implementation of JAX-RPC (**wscompile**)

2) WebLogic's **clientgen** (I used 8.1 version)

3) Axis1 v1.4 **wsdl2java**

Originally we used Axis 1.4 for that and it showed quite poor performance on relatively large service responses (>20k) i.e. client processing time increased more than twice comparing to plain HTTP request without parsing. And the time grows if response gets bigger. It took more than 30s to just deserialize 1MB large respose.

SUN's generated client didn't really work and it failed on request with the message:

```
unexpected element name: 
   expected=getSubscriberInfoReturn, 
   actual={ws.generated.api}getSubscriberInfoReturn
```

I have tried using WebLogic's 8.1 clientgen, and compared client code to Axis 1.4 generated client's performance. And Axis won the race. So, even though Axis client is performing not that good on relatively large responses it still is the best option out there for old rpc/encoded web services :(.

Comment: Could you show how to do  this precisely? When running `java -classpath path/to/axis-1_4/lib/ org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java` I got an `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java`

Comment: Man, it was 6 years ago :). Your error indicates you have issues with your classpath.

Answer (score 5):

RPC encoding is not supported on Axis2. Source: http://wiki.apache.org/ws/StackComparison

Answer (score 2):

Try Axis 1, I've used it for this exact reason.

Comment: Yes, we use Axis 1 at the moment, actualy. But we hit performance problems with that :(. Do you know of any other alternatives to Axis 1 or 2 or Apache CXF?

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with SimpleDataBinding in axis2 too. I resolved them by using the 
AxisDataBinding option. Which is bit more heavy weight from a coding perspective, 
but works after all.

[ADB in detail](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_0/adb/adb-howto.html)

Furthermore I'd agree to Robert, stating that axis1 is an interesting option too.

Answer (score 1):

You can add following parameter for `wsdl2java` command

```
-d xmlbeans
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to get in depth with this, but since you asked for alternatives:

Java 6 SE and Java 5 EE ship with the [Metro JAX-WS](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) (reference) implementation.

It lives in the [`javax.xml.ws`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/package-summary.html) namespace.

Sun's Developer Network has an article [Introducing JAX-WS 2.0 With the Java SE 6 Platform](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) that might be useful.

Having said all this, Eclipse is not very [JAX-WS friendly](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/Developing_with_Eclipse.html).

Comment: I would be happy to use JAX-WS, but JAX-WS does not support rpc/encoded style web services. And I cann't change the web service :(, but I need a client for that.

Comment: I have tried using JAX-RPC reference implementation and wscompile. After downloading all jars that SUN didn't include in normal distrubtion, I managed to generate the client, but it failed with exception: *Caused by: unexpected element name: expected=getSubscriberInfoReturn, actual={http://ws.generated.api}getSubscriberInfoReturn

Answer (score 0):

This issue raises if the soap encoding style is old
axis2 wsdl2java or wsimport cannot understand the old RPC encoding style
so use the axis 1.4 or older version of axis
the draw back is that u will not find wsdl2java as a tool in old axis
instead you will find it as a class file in the axis jar file
so u have to manually set a the classpath and use that class

> D:\axis-1_4\lib>java -classpath  \axis-1_4\lib* org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java urwsdl

Answer (score 0):

The answer post on soapenc.xsd found here 
[Clickatell SOAP wsdl to JAXB java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401661/clickatell-soap-wsdl-to-jaxb-java-classes?answertab=votes#tab-top)
helped me .

I was using wsdl2java utility of axis1.5, we got the similar error on array.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:271)
            at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
            at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(SimpleDBExtension.java:53)
            at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:224)
            ... 2 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(SimpleDBExtension.java:50)
            ... 3 more
    Caused by: org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompilationException: can not find type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}Array from the parent schema ....
            at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.copyMetaInfoHierarchy(SchemaCompiler.java:1296)
            at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexContent(SchemaCompiler.java:1258)
            at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processContentModel(SchemaCompiler.java:1153)
            at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1097)
            at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1017)
```

I tried updating my wsdl file by creating the soapenc.xsd with the contents from website 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'.
As shown below, this worked really for me.

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1= .. xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns=.. xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace=..>
<types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace=.. xmlns:ns1=.. xmlns:ns2=.. xmlns:tns=.. xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
</types>
<import location="soapenc.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
<message name="Input">
    <part name=../>
</message>
<message name="Output">
    <part name=../>
</message>
<portType name=".."> .. </portType>
<binding name="..." type="tns:"..">
    <operation name="...">          ..          </operation>
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
</binding>
<service name="...">
    <port binding="tns:..." name="...">         <soap:address location="..."/>      </port>
</service>
```